# MVC RazorGenerator - "Type (...) already defines a member called 'Execute' with the same parameter types"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorgenerator, precompiled-views

I've been working on a big MVC Application and now i need to improve application's startup performance (which is bad +1min for the first load).

I installed RazorGenerator nugget and the extension too, but when i compile a lot of errors appear.

[image: VS Errors]

May this be caused by not specifying the Generator Type?
Because i didn't find their documentation very helpful about this.

Or maybe because i added the following directive to one of my views (`_EditHelperPage.cshtml`) because it was rendering as `HelperPage` instead of `WebViewPage`:

```
@* Generator: MvcView *@
```

After i remove this line and adding it to `razorgenerator.directives`, it throws me another error:

[image: Helper Page Error]

**Edit**

And if i search for a class/constructor with the same name, it find results in `/obj/CodeGen/(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem.

Before i installed the VS Extension RazorGenerator (not the nugget!), i installed RazorGenerator.MsBuild which does the same as the extension but on build time (right?).

But why was it happening?
I think that the extension builds views before MsBuild, however they were doing the same and therefore creating duplicated `.cs` files

I just unistalled `.MsBuild` package and voilá, it works.

Comment: Nice catch. This was extremely helpful. After installing both the Extension AND the NuGet package, my solution was blowing up with hundreds of errors. Removing the RazorGenerator.MsBuild Nuget Package fixed the solution. Thanks!