# Asp.Net MVC website loading slow at first time or inactivity of 30 min

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

GoDaddy's server idle timeout is 5 min. If my website will hit every 5 min automatically then it will not suspend.Is there is any way to hit on server after every 5 min so the server will not remove cache.

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from the same...

I've made some several adjustments to be faster at the first call.

The main adjustment was to use Pre compiled views using Razor Generator. It compiles the views from .cshtml to .cshtml.cs it's like the codehind from ASPX

Here are some useful links.

[Razor Generator](https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/)

[SO Question by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310485/mvc-razorgenerator-type-already-defines-a-member-called-execute-with/34312173#34312173)

Another thing that i tried later, was to increase the IIS recycle period. But this doesn't resolve all the problems, since your are just increasing the time that's expected to get some activity in the website.

So I'm just saying that it's better to decrease the first load time than increasing the expected activity period or "hackings" like you suggest.

Comment: How much time does your first call takes?

Comment: It takes 40 to 50 sec after that 1-2 sec

Comment: Check if you have `<compliation debug="true"`

Comment: Dear I published my website from visual studio. I automatically remove that. I also published in release mode.